# Azure Security MFA Phone Call Settings

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I was hoping to switch the locale used in the Azure MFA "Call Me" function used in Azure AD B2C to *en-GB* rather than the default *en-US* (refers to "pressing the pound sign" which isn't a term we use in the UK).  It seems the best you can hope for is just a default English language with no regional/sub-culture options.

The backup plan is to record our own Greeting(s).  However the option to add your own greetings is grayed-out:

[image: Azure Security MFA phone call settings screen]

Does anyone know what precondition must be satisfied so I can access the "+ Add greeting" link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [list of all supported languages for multi-factor authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/language-customization?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#supported-languages) (MFA) notifications. This is triggered by the [ui_locales](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/language-customization?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#social-identity-provider-translations) query parameter presented in the URL or browser preference configuration set by user.

That MFA blade (your image) isn't entirely supported by Azure AD B2C. Review the primary documentation on [Customize language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/language-customization?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

Azure AD B2C does support connecting to [third-party MFA solution](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples#multi-factor) where you can add services such as customize voice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Does this explicitly mean that even if it was possible to configure custom greetings on this blade, that it's not possible to configure Azure AD B2C to use them?

Comment: AFAIK, custom greetings isn't supported on this blade. I'll tag a couple folks on my team double check my response and correct me.